# query r.e running for loop scripts in parallel

Tags: shell-script, parallelism

I have the following in a shell script:

```
for file in $local_dir/myfile.log.*; 
    do 
        file_name=$(basename $file); 
        server_name=$(echo $file_name | cut -f 3 -d '.');
        file_location=$(echo $file);

        mv $file_location $local_dir/in_progress1.log

        mysql -hxxx -P3306 -uxxx -pxxx -e "set @server_name='${server_name}'; source ${sql_script};"

        rm $local_dir/in_progress1.log
    done
```

It basically gets all files in a directory that match the criteria, extracts a servername from the filename, before passing it across to a MySQL script for procesing.

What I am wondering is if I have 10 files that take 60 seconds each to complete, and after 5 minutes I then start a second instance of the shell script:

- a) will the second script still see the files that havent been processed
- b) will it cause problems for the first instance if it deletes files

or will I be able to run them in parallel without issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One would assume that "60 seconds" (and even "5 minutes") is just a good estimate, and that there is a risk that the first batch is still in progress when the second batch is started.  If you want to separate the batches (and if there is no problem aside from the log-files in an occasional overlap), a better approach would be to make a batch number as part of the in-progress filenaming convention.

Something like this:

```
[[ -s ]] $local_dir/batch || echo 0 > $local_dir/batch
batch=$(echo $local_dir/batch)
expr $batch + 1 >$local_dir/batch
```

before the for-loop, and then at the start of the loop, check that your pattern matches an actual file

```
[[ -f "$file" ]] || continue
```

and use the batch number in the filename:

```
mv $file_location $local_dir/in_progress$batch.log
```

and for forth.  That reduces the risk of collision.

Comment: OK cheers, some files will take a second, others could take 20 minutes, so   I picked 60 seconds as an average. It sounds similar to what I was thinking, where I renamed the files inside the loop `in_progress1.log for script 1 and `in_progress2.log` for script2 etc. I'll see if I can make it work.

Answer (score 1):

There is an answer above that provides some good solutions to the problem, but I thought I would provide a bit of explanation on the *why* of what the problem is.

For the most part: as long as your renamed log files (the in progress ones) do not meet the criteria, you are *probably* safe to run this with **minimal** risk. You will still get some errors though...

Your list of files is generated on script run. So what would end up happening is that:

`Script A` gets a list of `10 files`. Begins processing, `5 files` in (5 remaining) `script B` gets a list of `5 remaining files`, begins processing. `Script a` then goes to process next file on its list(which is the same as the file `script B` has started to process) it will error because the file has been renamed. So with error handling, this it could theoretically move on to the next in its list and function without a problem. But, obviously there is ALWAYS the chance that the stars align, but scripts hit the same file at the same time, and something unexpected happens. Weigh that risk as you will.

A potentially more elegant solution would be to convert this to a `python` script and look into `parallel for loops` which would allow you to create a single for loop, and run through it in parallel, allowing one script to do the work of two or more.

Comment: cheers, I was wondering if the list was generated on runtime or after each file was picked up, You explained it really well. I like the idea of the Python script, alas it is one of the few languages I've not spent much time with for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is to implement a simple batch queue in your script.

At the start of the script, you could do something like this:

```sh
mkdir -p $localdir/batch
BATCHTMP=$(mktemp batch.XXXXXXXXXX)
MYBATCH="$localdir/batch/batch.$$"

# get list of current log files
find $local_dir/ -name 'myfile.log.*' > "$BATCHTMP"

# exclude any log files already in other batches
grep -vF -f <(sort -u $localdir/batch/batch.*) < "$BATCHTMP" > "$MYBATCH"

rm -f "$BATCHTMP"

# only process log files that are in my batch
for lf in $(cat "$MYBATCH") ; do
....
# somewhere in here, mv or rm the logfile being processed
# so it doesn't get processed again in a later batch run
done

rm -f "$MYBATCH"
```

This is, of course, only a simple outline of what needs to be done.

BTW, this could also be done in a wrapper script that does nothing but generate the batch file and then run the main script.

Comment: cheers, Looking at this When it runs the section `BATCHTMP=$(mktemp batch)` and `BATCHTMP2` it gives the error `mktemp: too few X's in template batch'`

Comment: @IGGt,  fixed. added `.XXXXXXXXXX` to the `mktemp`, also removed unnecessary $BATCHTMP2

Comment: cheers, (sorry,Ive been away), when I run this `$MYBATCH` is always `/batch/batch.24500`. Should this be different each time? On the line `grep -vF. . . .` I then just get `permission denied errors` every time. Even with `sudo`.

Comment: $$ is the PID of the sh/bash process that runs the script, so it's supposed to be different on every run.  re: permissions, does the bigger script set the umask to something unusual, without read permission?

Comment: OK, the $$ makes sense now. I checked permissions on `$local_dir/batch` and it looks fine (set to 777 to make sure), also my test `myfile.*` looked normal, but I set them to 777 as well, but still get the same error `-bash: /batch/batch.1400: Permission denied` followed by `sort: open failed: /batch/batch.*: No such file or directory`

Comment: i think you have to `export localdir` so it is available in the sub-shell used for the process substitution `<( sort ... )`

Comment: sorry (still new to this) but how would I do that? I tried replacing `$local_dir` with the actual path, and I no longer get `sort: open failed` error. But I still get `-bash: /batch/batch.5291: Permission denied`. I tried `chmod 777 ... ` on everything in $local_dir, but it's still the same.

Comment: blindly running `chmod 777` is not a solution to anything.  in short order you'll find it's the source of numerous problems.  try creating the $MYBATCH file somewhere outside of $local_dir/batch/ (e.g. another tmpfile created with mktemp) and then mv-ing it there after the `grep -vF` has run.